# Load MySQL table faster

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Trying to load a 2Gb txt file into MySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE  and it's taking >2days. Any one of you experts know what I need to do to get the data to load faster? Are there some settings I can change to max the CPU usage or something?

My settings are as follows:

```
auto_increment_increment=1
auto_increment_offset=1
autocommit=ON
automatic_sp_privileges=ON
back_log=80
big_tables=OFF
bind_address=*
binlog_cache_size=32768
binlog_checksum=CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates=OFF
binlog_format=STATEMENT
binlog_max_flush_queue_time=0
binlog_order_commits=ON
binlog_row_image=FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events=OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size=32768
binlogging_impossible_mode=IGNORE_ERROR
bulk_insert_buffer_size=8388608
character_set_client=utf8
character_set_connection=utf8
character_set_database=utf8
character_set_filesystem=binary
character_set_results=utf8
character_set_server=utf8
character_set_system=utf8
collation_connection=utf8_general_ci
collation_database=utf8_general_ci
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
completion_type=NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert=AUTO
connect_timeout=10
core_file=OFF
date_format=%Y-%m-%d
datetime_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine=InnoDB
default_week_format=0
delay_key_write=ON
delayed_insert_limit=100
delayed_insert_timeout=300
delayed_queue_size=1000
disconnect_on_expired_password=ON
div_precision_increment=4
end_markers_in_json=OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency=OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit=10
error_count=0
event_scheduler=OFF
expire_logs_days=0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=OFF
external_user=
flush=OFF
flush_time=0
foreign_key_checks=ON
ft_boolean_syntax=+ -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len=84
ft_min_word_len=4
ft_query_expansion_limit=20
ft_stopword_file=(built-in)
general_log=OFF
group_concat_max_len=1024
gtid_executed=
gtid_mode=OFF
gtid_next=AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned=
gtid_purged=
have_compress=YES
have_crypt=NO
have_dynamic_loading=YES
have_geometry=YES
have_openssl=DISABLED
have_profiling=YES
have_query_cache=YES
have_rtree_keys=YES
have_ssl=DISABLED
have_symlink=YES
host_cache_size=279
identity=0
ignore_builtin_innodb=OFF
ignore_db_dirs=
init_connect=
init_file=
init_slave=
innodb_adaptive_flushing=ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm=10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2097152
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval=5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock=OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog=OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl=OFF
innodb_api_trx_level=0
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now=OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename=ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort=OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now=OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size=38797312
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=25
innodb_change_buffering=all
innodb_checksum_algorithm=crc32
innodb_checksums=ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled=OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency=0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct=5
innodb_compression_level=6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max=50
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_data_home_dir=
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache=OFF
innodb_doublewrite=ON
innodb_fast_shutdown=1
innodb_file_format=Antelope
innodb_file_format_check=ON
innodb_file_format_max=Antelope
innodb_file_per_table=ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_flush_method=
innodb_flush_neighbors=1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=30
innodb_force_load_corrupted=OFF
innodb_force_recovery=0
innodb_ft_aux_table=
innodb_ft_cache_size=8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print=OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size=84
innodb_ft_min_token_size=3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize=2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit=2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table=
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree=2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size=640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table=
innodb_io_capacity=200
innodb_io_capacity_max=2000
innodb_large_prefix=OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size=1048576
innodb_log_compressed_pages=ON
innodb_log_file_size=50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_log_group_home_dir=.\
innodb_lru_scan_depth=1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0
innodb_max_purge_lag=0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay=0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups=1
innodb_monitor_disable=
innodb_monitor_enable=
innodb_monitor_reset=
innodb_monitor_reset_all=
innodb_old_blocks_pct=37
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size=134217728
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=OFF
innodb_page_size=16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size=300
innodb_purge_threads=1
innodb_random_read_ahead=OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold=56
innodb_read_io_threads=4
innodb_read_only=OFF
innodb_replication_delay=0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout=OFF
innodb_rollback_segments=128
innodb_sort_buffer_size=1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay=6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc=ON
innodb_stats_method=nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata=OFF
innodb_stats_persistent=ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages=20
innodb_stats_sample_pages=8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages=8
innodb_status_output=OFF
innodb_status_output_locks=OFF
innodb_strict_mode=OFF
innodb_support_xa=ON
innodb_sync_array_size=1
innodb_sync_spin_loops=30
innodb_table_locks=ON
innodb_thread_concurrency=9
innodb_thread_sleep_delay=0
innodb_undo_directory=.
innodb_undo_logs=128
innodb_undo_tablespaces=0
innodb_use_native_aio=ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc=ON
innodb_version=5.6.21
innodb_write_io_threads=4
insert_id=0
interactive_timeout=28800
join_buffer_size=262144
keep_files_on_create=OFF
key_buffer_size=8388608
key_cache_age_threshold=300
key_cache_block_size=1024
key_cache_division_limit=100
large_files_support=ON
large_page_size=0
large_pages=OFF
last_insert_id=0
lc_messages=en_US
lc_time_names=en_US
local_infile=ON
lock_wait_timeout=31536000
log_bin=OFF
log_bin_basename=
log_bin_index=
log_bin_trust_function_creators=OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events=OFF
log_output=FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes=OFF
log_slave_updates=OFF
log_slow_admin_statements=OFF
log_slow_slave_statements=OFF
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes=0
log_warnings=1
long_query_time=10
low_priority_updates=OFF
lower_case_file_system=ON
lower_case_table_names=1
master_info_repository=FILE
master_verify_checksum=OFF
max_allowed_packet=4194304
max_binlog_cache_size=18446744073709500000
max_binlog_size=1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size=18446744073709500000
max_connect_errors=100
max_connections=151
max_delayed_threads=20
max_error_count=64
max_heap_table_size=16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads=20
max_join_size=18446744073709500000
max_length_for_sort_data=1024
max_prepared_stmt_count=16382
max_relay_log_size=0
max_seeks_for_key=4294967295
max_sort_length=1024
max_sp_recursion_depth=0
max_tmp_tables=32
max_user_connections=0
max_write_lock_count=4294967295
metadata_locks_cache_size=1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances=8
min_examined_row_limit=0
multi_range_count=256
myisam_data_pointer_size=6
myisam_max_sort_file_size=107374182400
myisam_mmap_size=4294967295
myisam_recover_options=OFF
myisam_repair_threads=1
myisam_sort_buffer_size=16777216
myisam_stats_method=nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap=OFF
named_pipe=ON
net_buffer_length=16384
net_read_timeout=30
net_retry_count=10
net_write_timeout=60
new=OFF
old=OFF
old_alter_table=OFF
old_passwords=0
open_files_limit=6209
optimizer_prune_level=1
optimizer_search_depth=62
optimizer_trace_limit=1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size=16384
optimizer_trace_offset=-1
performance_schema=ON
performance_schema_accounts_size=100
performance_schema_digests_size=10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size=10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size=10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size=10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size=10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size=10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size=10
performance_schema_hosts_size=100
performance_schema_max_cond_classes=80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances=3504
performance_schema_max_file_classes=50
performance_schema_max_file_handles=32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances=6770
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes=200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances=15906
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes=40
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances=9102
performance_schema_max_socket_classes=10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances=322
performance_schema_max_stage_classes=150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes=168
performance_schema_max_table_handles=4000
performance_schema_max_table_instances=12500
performance_schema_max_thread_classes=50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances=402
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size=512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size=100
performance_schema_setup_objects_size=100
performance_schema_users_size=100
port=3306
preload_buffer_size=32768
profiling=OFF
profiling_history_size=15
protocol_version=10
proxy_user=
pseudo_slave_mode=OFF
pseudo_thread_id=14
query_alloc_block_size=8192
query_cache_limit=1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit=4096
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate=OFF
query_prealloc_size=8192
rand_seed1=0
rand_seed2=0
range_alloc_block_size=4096
read_buffer_size=32768
read_only=OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size=262144
relay_log=
relay_log_basename=
relay_log_index=
relay_log_info_file=relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository=FILE
relay_log_purge=ON
relay_log_recovery=OFF
relay_log_space_limit=0
report_host=
report_password=
report_port=3306
report_user=
rpl_stop_slave_timeout=31536000
secure_auth=ON
secure_file_priv=
server_id=1
server_id_bits=32
shared_memory=ON
shared_memory_base_name=MYSQL
simplified_binlog_gtid_recovery=OFF
skip_external_locking=ON
skip_name_resolve=OFF
skip_networking=OFF
skip_show_database=OFF
slave_allow_batching=OFF
slave_checkpoint_group=512
slave_checkpoint_period=300
slave_compressed_protocol=OFF
slave_exec_mode=STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir=C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp
slave_max_allowed_packet=1073741824
slave_net_timeout=3600
slave_parallel_workers=0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max=16777216
slave_rows_search_algorithms=TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors=OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum=ON
slave_transaction_retries=10
slave_type_conversions=
slow_launch_time=2
slow_query_log=ON
socket=MYSQL
sort_buffer_size=262144
sql_auto_is_null=OFF
sql_big_selects=ON
sql_buffer_result=OFF
sql_log_bin=ON
sql_log_off=OFF
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes=ON
sql_quote_show_create=ON
sql_safe_updates=OFF
sql_select_limit=18446744073709500000
sql_slave_skip_counter=0
sql_warnings=OFF
ssl_ca=
ssl_capath=
ssl_cert=
ssl_cipher=
ssl_crl=
ssl_crlpath=
ssl_key=
storage_engine=InnoDB
stored_program_cache=256
sync_binlog=0
sync_frm=ON
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
system_time_zone=Pacific Daylight Time
table_definition_cache=1400
table_open_cache=2000
table_open_cache_instances=1
thread_cache_size=10
thread_concurrency=10
thread_handling=one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack=196608
timestamp=1412831034.49334
tmp_table_size=13631488
transaction_alloc_block_size=8192
transaction_allow_batching=OFF
transaction_prealloc_size=4096
tx_isolation=REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only=OFF
unique_checks=ON
updatable_views_with_limit=YES
wait_timeout=28800
warning_count=0
```

Comment: Have you tuned your server at all or are you running with the awful defaults that MySQL comes with? What format is your file? Have you done tests on other hardware? Are you using SSDs? Why did you not post **more detail**?

Comment: Just added more info. Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way a 2G file should take days to load. It should only take minutes, at worst.

You're using MySQL 5.6, but you're still using the default settings for MySQL 5.5. They are really inadequate.

I'd recommend changing at least these settings for starters:

- innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G (assuming you have enough RAM that this won't cause swapping)
- innodb_log_file_size=2G
- innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
- innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

You need to restart mysqld to put these into effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your delay is because for each insert, the system has got to check for integrity, constraints, etc. So for example, each time an insert takes place, indexes get rebuilt... Now that's only an example.

If you can guarantee that your data meets integrity constraints, here's what I'd do. First make sure that database is not being used by other users at this moment, here's what you need to do:

1. Remove all primary key constraints and indexes. (I don't know if there's a method to simply turn them off)
2. Bring your new data in
3. Recreate your indexes and keys.

This can be quite tricky so using a script to do it should be the best option.

Comment: Indexes are not rebuilt for every row inserted. Adding one entry to an index is not that costly. FWIW, there's no way to turn off a primary key for an InnoDB table. If you try, the table creates its own hidden primary key.